# google app engine request duration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

how i can overcome the 60 seconds limitation. 
i read that configure the yaml file to manual_scaling will help but it didn't. after 60 sec the server reset. the server developed with nodesjs
i need to send 2000 emails every x time. i need the ability to run process for 10-20 minutes
this is the yaml file:

```js
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: B4

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use the "default" service.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine

Try to use the manual scaling in another service of your application, you have to add this xml tag in your appengine-web.xml file to achieve this.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#service

This is not the best solution yet, you should use App Engine Tasks to do a long-running operation.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/

Comment: they support nodejs ?

Comment: yes sure.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/nodejs/
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files

Comment: Did you try basic scaling?